# How to get dynamic hex format variable width with leading zeros?

Tags: variables

strlen(var) can return length without leading zeros.
How to include leading zeros?
Example `let var=0x00001234`, width shall be 8 instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VimScript variables have (dynamic) types. After `let var=0x00001234` the variable's value is a number `4660`. `strlen()` silently converts number `4660` into a string `"4660"`, therefore the "string length" is 4.

You can use explicit typecasts:

```
let varstring = "00001234"
let varnumber = str2nr(var, 16)
echo varnumber strlen(varstring) "4660 8
```

Also you can simply `let var="0x00001234"` and rely on automatic conversion, however `strlen('0x00001234')` is equal to 10.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with hexadecimal (or decimal) numbers, since `0x0001234` is actually just `0x1234`, there's no way to "save" the leading zeros anywhere. And the variable simply cannot know that it was declared with leading zeros.

You need to just pass the variable as a string to have it know it's length with the zeros, then you can convert it to a hex number, when you're ready to use it:

```
let var = '00001234'
echo strlen(var)  " 8

let var = str2nr(var, 16)
" use var here
echo strlen(var)  " 4 (since var == 4660 in decimal)
```

Comment: var is a dynamic variable. strlen(var) = 4

Comment: @Fisher See my edit :)